# Unable to Authenticate using Face Recognition with Expo SecureStore

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm attempting to save/retrieve a value from [Expo SecureStore](https://www.npmjs.com/package/expo-secure-store) using the requireAuthentication option.

Using an Android device, when I'm registered for Fingerprint biometrics, I'm able to successfully save/retrieve a value. However, when I switch to Face Recognition I'm unable to save/retrieve a value. The error coming back from SecureStore is `ERR_SECURESTORE_AUTH_NOT_CONFIGURED No biometrics are currently enrolled`. I'm able to get it working on some Android devices.

I have raised a [GitHub](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/26615) issue with a simple example of the problem. In the example, I am able to successfully save a value to SecureStore when I'm registered for Fingerprint biometrics but I can't save a value when I am registered for Face Recognition.

I believe that I'm successfully enrolled for Face Recognition as I can use it to unlock my device and it also works when using `authenticateAsync` from `expo-local-authentication`.

I would expect it to work the same regardless of whether I am using Fingerprint or Face Recognition.

Is there any special configuration needed to get facial recognition working with expo-secure-store?

Answer (score 0):

As alluded to in the linked github issue above, this seems to be caused by SecureStore requiring Class 3 biometrics (BIOMETRIC_STRONG) but expo-local-authentication only required Class 2 Biometrics (BIOMETIC_WEAK).

As Facial Recognition on most Android devices (excluding Pixel 4/8) is only considered Class 2 (BIOMETRIC_WEAK) it is not supported by SecureStore, hence the `ERR_SECURESTORE_AUTH_NOT_CONFIGURED` error code.

It would be useful if `expo-local-authentication`, `expo-secure-store` or both provided an option to configure the level of Biometrics you want to enforce but for now, I have used `patch-package` to enforce the `isEnrolledAsync` from `expo-local-authentication` to use BIOMETRIC_STRONG as outlined in this [issue](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/17804)